# What's the polars equivalent to the pandas `.iloc` method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-polars

I'm looking for the recommended way to select an individual row of a `polars.DataFrame` by row number: something largely equivalent to `pandas.DataFrame`'s `.iloc[[n]]` method for a given integer `n`.

For polars imported as `pl` and a polars DataFrame `df`, my current approach would be:

```py
# for example
n = 3

# create row count, filter for individual row, drop the row count.
new_df = (
    df.with_row_count()
    .filter(pl.col('row_nr') == n)
    .select(pl.exclude('row_nr'))
)
```

I'm migrating from Pandas, and I've read the Pandas-to-Polars [migration guide](https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/migration/pandas/), but a slick solution to this specific case wasn't addressed there. *Edit: to clarify, I am looking for an approach that returns a `polars.DataFrame` object for the chosen row.*

Does anyone have something slicker?

Comment: It would probably depend on what you're doing with the row. For "quick", "interactive" usage `df[3]` works - but wouldn't be "recommended" if you were composing larger expressions.

Comment: It seems the Polars does not really use an index. The focus in on the data and not the index.

Comment: But you can set a column as the index via ```polars.DataFrame.with_row_index```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a very good sheet by: @Liam Brannigan

Credit to them.

**https://www.rhosignal.com/posts/polars-pandas-cheatsheet/**

A glimse from the sheet:

[image]

**You can find other information related to Filtering Rows using `iloc` and its equivalent in polars in the sheet.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess, the direct equivalent of `.iloc` from [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) is the [`.row()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.row.html) method in [polars](/questions/tagged/polars).

If you have a dataframe, `df`:

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "foo": [1, 2, 3],
        "bar": [6, 7, 8],
        "ham": ["a", "b", "c"],
    }
)
```

Here's how you'd access a row:

```
df.row(2)
(3, 8, 'c')
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this - I was looking for an approach that returns a dataframe object - I'll clarify in the question.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. I didn't understand that from the original question.